# Bimap To large For Memory

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, game-development

I am coding a game in java similar to Among us (A game where the important part, for now, is that players see only part of a big map) and the way I was drawing the map is with a bitmap that is several times larger than the screen, and  I move the position of the map around, but the bitmap is too large for the memory, does anyone have an idea to help me fix this?
or a different idea for loading the map?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, most map UIs (whether with real maps or game maps) use a tile system, where the map is divided into tiles that get loaded and unloaded as needed. See Peter Laurence's libraries for [the classic `View` system](https://github.com/p-lr/MapView) and [Compose UI](https://github.com/p-lr/MapCompose).

And, if you are developing a game, see if your game framework offers some sort of map solution.